# pyplot different behaviour from 2.1.1 from 2.2.2

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I've done a python script for preparing my plot.. I prepare this using debian in which the version of matplot lib is 2.1.1 , while now I'm moving to Archlinux in which I deal with version 2.2.2 , the problem is that while in 2.1.1 I define all the parameter (for example the cycler colors) in this way :

```
plt.rc_context({ 'axes.prop_cycle': cycler('color', ['#8DA0CB', '#E78AC3', '#A6D854', '#FFD92F', '#E5C494', '#B3B3B3', '#66C2A5', '#FC8D62'] )})
```

in 2.2.2 I found this solution:

```
plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=(cycler('color', ['#8DA0CB', '#E78AC3', '#A6D854', '#FFD92F', '#E5C494', '#B3B3B3', '#66C2A5', '#FC8D62'])))
```

the problem is that I've define all this parameter:

```
plt.rc_context({'axes.edgecolor': self.parameter['box'] })   # BOX colors
         plt.rc_context({'axes.linewidth':'1.2' })   # BOX width
         plt.rc_context({'axes.xmargin':'0' })     
         plt.rc_context({'axes.ymargin':'0' })     
         plt.rc_context({'axes.labelcolor':self.parameter['axeslabel']})     
         plt.rc_context({'axes.axisbelow':'True' })     
         plt.rc_context({'xtick.color': self.parameter['xtickcolor']})   # doesn't affect the text
         plt.rc_context({'ytick.color': self.parameter['ytickcolor']})   # doesn't affect the text
         #plt.rc_context({ 'axes.prop_cycle': self.colors('tthmod')}) 
         plt.rc_context({ 'axes.prop_cycle': cycler('color', ['#8DA0CB', '#E78AC3', '#A6D854', '#FFD92F', '#E5C494', '#B3B3B3', '#66C2A5', '#FC8D62'] )}) 
         plt.rc_context({ 'grid.linestyle': '--'}) 
         plt.rc_context({ 'grid.alpha': '1'})
         #plt.rc_context({ 'grid.color': '#E5E5E5'})
         plt.rc_context({ 'grid.color': '#FFFFFF'})
```

where I can find a solution ?? I mean a way to let's works "my way" or how to change the syntax in order to get the same result ! thanks

EDIT si ma perche` non mi prende quelle versioni che avevo scritto (cosa che faceva la versione 2.1.1) mi lascia pensare che qualcosa sia cambiato!!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. There are several ways to specify rc parameters and you are free to choose the one you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way to specify many rc parameters at once is to use a dictionary and update the `matplotlib.rcParams` with it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler

myparams = {'axes.edgecolor': "red",   # BOX colors
            'axes.linewidth': 1.2,   # BOX width
            'axes.xmargin': 0,    
            'axes.ymargin': 0,     
            'axes.labelcolor': "crimson",     
            'axes.axisbelow': True,   
            'xtick.color': "blue",   # doesn't affect the text
            'ytick.color': "gold",   # doesn't affect the text 
            'axes.prop_cycle': cycler('color', ['#8DA0CB', '#E78AC3', '#A6D854', '#FFD92F', '#E5C494', '#B3B3B3', '#66C2A5', '#FC8D62']), 
            'grid.linestyle': '--', 
            'grid.alpha': '1',
            'grid.color': '#E5E5E5'}
plt.rcParams.update(myparams)
```

If instead you want to use a context, you may do so

```
with plt.rc_context(myparams):
    plt.plot([1,2,3])
```

Using `plt.rc_context` outside of a context (as in the question) may not make too much sense anyways.